# Playright loop while condition is met in addition to that keep clicking on refresh button every 10 seconds until locator found

Tags: while-loop, playwright, expect, assertion

I am waiting for a text within a locator that only displays itself after a few minutes but the page won't reload on its own to show it - we have a standard refresh button that needs to be clicked occasionally. There are 3 stages of the text that dynamically change. Stage 1 = 'Pending', Stage 2 = 'Running', Stage 3 = 'Completed'. Of course, if the text turns into 'Failed', it should fail the whole test. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show an example and a [mcve] of your code so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [expect.toPass()](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions#expecttopass) to retry until it pass:

```js
test('Expect completed', async ({ page }) => {
  await expect(async () => {
    await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'refresh' }).click()
    await expect(page.getByText('Completed')).toBeVisible()
  }).toPass({ intervals: [30_000, 60_000, 90_000, 120_000] })
  // Retries every half minute for 2 minutes
})
```

EDIT: A second approach that sets the timeout of the test to 15 minutes and retrying every 10 second using a promise with timeout:

```js
test("Expect completed 2", async ({ page }) => {
  test.setTimeout(15 * 60 * 1_000); // 15 minutes
  while (await page.getByText("Completed").isHidden()) {
    await Promise.all([
      page.getByRole("heading", { name: "refresh" }).click(),
      new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 10_000)),
    ]);
  }
  // If test exits the loop, it will pass. If not it will fail cause of the test timeout
});
```

Comment: Thank you! But how can I increase the 2 minute wait time for like 10 or 15 min wait time?

Comment: Intervals are set in milliseconds, 15 minutes would be 15*60*1000. You would also need to increase the test timeout in the playwright.config file.

Comment: So what would happen if I do this ? .toPass({ intervals: [15*60*1000] })
Would that simply retry in 15 mins and then end ? I would like it to retry every half a second like you did but for 15 minutes instead of 2 minutes if that makes sense? Thanks

Comment: Exactly, will be done only once after 15 minutes. I edited my answer with a second approach that might be better for your need of retrying that rapid.

Comment: Thank you, I can see that your edited code now clicks every 10s on the refresh button for the next 15 minutes until the text is not hidden anymore. That end bit logic .isHidden() puzzles a bit, would it still work without it being there?

Comment: If you remove the [while loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) and condition, the test will press the button once, wait 10 seconds and exit test without retrying.

Comment: Ah I see so your second example will basically keep pressing refresh button every 10 seconds whiles its not there for the next 15 minutes. That will work. Thank you!

Comment: Hey candre, the test actually failed upon exiting the loop because await page.getByText("Completed").isHidden() stoped being true i.e. is became visible. I would need it the test to be pass if that happens and not fail.